# Is there a way to access the actual Audio spoken from Twilio's VoiceResponse?

Tags: twilio, webrtc, twilio-api

I have been tasked with evaluating Twilio for our current project where we are wanting to perform semi-real time transliteration on a call between two parties that do not speak the same language.  Therefore we need the full sentence to be spoken before sending it off to our API for transliteration.

Using Twilios runtime functions, I have been able to catch the event.SpeechResult and pass that off for transliteration however management is asking as to whether we can get the audio spoken itself (representative of the speechResult).

I am currently looking at trying to setup a RESTful path to set for my recording server and see if that provides me something, but I have a feeling that it may only work with the full audio recording that we get under recordings in the dash.

I have been scouring the docs and google and have not been able to find anything as of yet and felt I would post here to see if anyone had any definitive answers in whether this could be done and some direction I should be looking.

Comment: Have a look at [web-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-audio) or [web-mediarecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-mediarecorder?sort=votes).

Comment: Thanks jib!  Going to go check these out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had seen in the API docs to use getRemoteStream and getLocalStream but I was getting access issues when trying to use.  In the end I found that the calls were only supported in the latest versions and I had previously manged to reference a static version of twilio.js in my project.  After upgrading to the latest, making references to these functions did the trick. Audio recorded sounds a little low quality, so going to delve into that but thought I'd post for anyone else dealing with something similar.